# Can't close Visual Studio 2012: "You must stop the current publish operation..." message

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 11.0.60315.01 Update 2.

I cannot close my Web Application project. When I try to do so, I get:
"You must stop the current publish operation or wait for it complete before closing."

The trouble is that I published to the web server before this and it looked like it had succeeded.

What can I check to get past this issue?

Comment: Hard to diagnose since you appear to be the only programmer out of 4 million that seems to have this problem, assuming you quoted the message correctly.  File a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com about it or contact Microsoft Support if you can't afford to wait.

Comment: well I just encounter it

Comment: As Hans suggested I filed a feedback report, was then asked to submit a screenshot of the issue, which I did, and have yet to hear from them again. I had to restart my workstation, the issue went away and hopefully will never return again. @Calin, I would go straight to Microsoft Support and not waste time with feedback.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, had to force close VS2013.

Comment: I'm having this issue with vs2017.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I hit the cancel button on a publish.

I made sure I hade everything saved and then just cancelled VS in task manager.
Then it was good after that.

Comment: It comes back when reloading VS...

Comment: yeah, I had to kill the process for VS2022. I clean and rebuild the solution before I publish now on and the hang goes away.